# Update the same table if INSERTED or UPDATED

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a table with 4 fields (ID  is auto generated)

```
CREATE TABLE MASTER_ARCH ( 
  ID NUMBER(5),
  NAME VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  AGE NUMBER(3),
  LAST_MOD_DT DATE 
);
```

My requirement is, if the table is getting inserted by new rows or updating existing rows then value for the column LAST_MOD_DT should be SYSDATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MASTER_ARCH 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.LAST_MOD_DT := sysdate;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. :) In my case i had to change the trigger definition a little bit and it worked fine.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help. You can share what you had to edit and maybe mark this answer as correct if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add,

```
create or replace TRIGGER MASTER_ARCH_DT 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MASTER_ARCH
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.LAST_MOD_DT := sysdate;
END;
```